# Materials not rendering!

Tags: rendering, materials

I'm pretty new to blender and trying to finish a simple animation of a kaleidoscope that I modeled. It looks fine in the viewport and all of the materials are assigned, but when I render it shows up pink. All of my materials were made by changing settings for the Principled BSDF. [This is what the render looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpY0D.png),  [and this is what I'm seeing in the viewport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yg6b.jpg). [Here's the top of my materials panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0q6o.png). I don't know what's helpful to show, but I can upload any other screenshots, just let me know! I'm sure I'm just missing something simple but I've tried everything I can think of. Any tips are appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: You should follow Duarte's advice and upload the images directly in the question. Then you also instantly see that the link you've called "This is what the render looks like" is exactly the same image as "Here's the top of my materials panel". So we can't see what your render looks like, we only see your materials panel twice.

Answer (score 1):

It can be a little confusing at first to figure out how materials are applied and to which objects. Are you sure the object you're rendering is the one to which you've applied the pictured texture? You seem to have a lot of similarly named objects in the animation.

I'd recommend you make sure you don't have duplicate objects in the same space, and then make sure the material is applied to the one visible in the render.

Good luck!